# Fix Hijacked Event Handling of Click-Events

Tags: javascript, html

For a few years now I use user-JavaScript to put additional input buttons and clickable `span`-elements on pages. Usually I manage to make this work, e.g.

```
        span = document.createElement("span");
        span.onclick = __oujs.onClickAddPage;
        span.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Add page"));
        containingDiv.appendChild(span);
```

Usually `__oujs.onClickAddPage()` is called when I click on that `span`-element.

However, yesterday a site made some changes (apparently I have no clue what they were) that causes clicking on my elements to not cause any events. In the example above `__oujs.onClickAddPage()` is not called any more. The same is true for `input`-elements of type "button".

As I'm using Opera, DragonFly shows that my `span` still is the top-most element in that particular area and, therefore, it should handle the click-event. However, I understand that they include jQuery, which might be part of the misery.

Is there a special technique (maybe with a name that Google knows of) they use to able to do such thing? How do I get the control back and have my code called again? Can I remove some object?

I'm sorry for asking in a rather broad style, but I have no clue what I can look for to fix this myself. Please ask if you need to know something.

Comment: Do you have any errors in javascript console?
In general, you can examine the script of the page to see what's happening and debug the `__oujs.onClickAddPage` method call.

Comment: @Mr_Mig As I said, the function is not called any more, there is nothing I could debug. And there are no errors in the console.

Comment: Is `__oujs.onClickAddPage` is a method from site's script? Can you `console.log` this method to check whether it is defined and accessible at all?

Comment: @Mr_Mig No, that's my function. Yes, my code is still available and continues to work if I call it via the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*To get this off my open questions I answer this myself rather than waiting for it to be closed:*

I'm sorry, it was my fault. I had a stupid mistake in another user-JavaScript file that affected all sites...

I reinstalled my browser and was thinking about reinstalling my OS, but luckily this isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you this steps:

1. Create the next function:

   ```
   function stubFn(event){
     console.log('event caught', event); // this will log the click event
     __oujs.onClickAddPage.call(event.currentTarget, event); // emulate the onclick behavior
   }
   ```
2. Use `span.addEventListener('click', stubFn)` to add the listener to the element in your code.

If it does not work, then you have to reverse-engineer the script and markup.

I'd suggest to check if there is any element with `absolute` or `fixed` position overlapping your span. It can **prevent the event propagation**.

In general, there are no ways to forbid the elements from userscripts to handle events using inlined handlers.

Comment: Nope, sorry, didn't work, `stubFn()` doesn't get called. As I lined out in my question my items seem to be on top. I understand that they can't forbid my code, but maybe they can catch/redirect/trap/hijack/... the internal event handling or something.

Comment: As far as I know they cannot hijack the inlined event listeners. They can hijack the events constructors itself, but this idea need thorough  reverse engineering. 
If I were you, I would use the chrome dev tools and a couple of beers to dive into debugging and reverse engineering of their scripts.

Btw, you can use google cache to try to fetch their old site with old scripts and diff it with the new ones to see what have changed.